# Saving and Restoring instance state with Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
{
    savedInstanceStateBundle.putInt(AVERAGE_SESSION_VALUE_HOLDER, averageSessionSeek.getProgress());
    savedInstanceStateBundle.putInt(CONFIDENCE_VALUE_HOLDER, confidenceSeek.getProgress());
    savedInstanceStateBundle.putInt(CONVERSION_TIME_VALUE_HOLDER, conersionTimeSeek.getProgress());

}
```

Above code is belongs to `InputFragment.java` which extends `Fragment`. The above methods saves the state of instances so when the user navigate away from that particular `Fragment` and come back to it, the instances are restored. I tried it with the below code

```
@Override 
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
{

}
```

But it fails, compile errors. So, how can I reload the instance states in `Fragments`?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments don't have onRestoreInstanceState… it's onActivityCreated() (for technical reasons this was horribly implemented this way by the Android team).

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413327/2684) on StackOverflow for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) say this:

> Called to ask the fragment to save its current dynamic state, so it can later be reconstructed in a new instance of its process is restarted. If a new instance of the fragment later needs to be created, the data you place in the Bundle here will be available in the Bundle given to **onCreate(Bundle), onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), and onActivityCreated(Bundle).**
>
> This corresponds to Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and most of the discussion there applies here as well.

Instead of onSaveInstanceState(), use onActivityCreated(Bundle).

Comment: So where should I put restore code?

Comment: in onActivityCreated(Bundle), see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)